# htaccess: forcing https and www if not on localhost

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I work on my localhost so I need this exception in my mod_rewrite rule. Currently, I am able to force the "www" when not on localhost using the following:

```
# Force www, if not in localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now, I want to also force https (my entire site will be under https). How do I add this to my htaccess?

I tried making my htaccess like this, but this is forcing https on my localhost also:

```
# Force https, if not in localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Force www, if not in localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I think I need to remove the first `[R=301,L]`.

**UPDATE 2:**
If I have a URL like this: `https://scripts.domain.com`, I do not want it to become: `https://www.scripts.domain.com`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line above your last rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]{3}$
```

Comment: can you elaborate on your regex? Are you addressing the problem I specified in update #2? what about my https problem?

Comment: It will only match against things like `domain.com`, the first `[^.]+` matches everything that starts with at least one or more characters that isn't a dot, then the dot, then 3 characters at the end. The HTTPS I thought was working for some reason. I put those rules in my htaccess and it doesn't redirect `http://localhost/` to https. You don't want to get rid of `[R=301,L]`, you want to make sure your `HTTP_HOST` is actually `localhost`.

Comment: Why 3 characters in the end? What about .us? Or .co.nz? Etc? I'll retest https issue. It should be working, right?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie if you want to also cover the xx.xx TLD's, then change it to: `([^.]{2,4}|[^.]{2}\.[^.]{2})`, which would cover TLD's like `domain.jp`, `domain.co.jp`, `domain.us`, `domain.org`, `domain.info` etc.

Comment: @JonLin can you help me with this thing looks similar but a quite little difficult for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016986/htaccess-is-being-forefully-used-for-localhost