# .htaccess is being forefully used for localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, localhost, wamp

I am using wamp-server as on localhost with a virtual host named `www.xyz.com` i have a deployment service set through git which deploys code to server on `www.xyz.in`

This is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

The above code will make your domain to add `https` prefix

The problem with this code is that on `server` the code works perfect bu on `localhost` also it works like `https:// www.xyz.com`, but on `localhost` there is no such `https` thing. So is there any solution to this code that it should avoid putting `https` as a prefix on `localhost` and work as it is on `online server`.

I am expecting something like this from the above code:

1.) If I call the URL on localhost (www.xyz.com) - It should be as it is like (`www.xyz.com`)

2.) If I call URL on server (`www.xyz.in` or `xyz.in`) - It should be like (`https://www.xyz.in`)

Any helps appreciated.

Comment: So just add another condition checking that hostname isn't localhost.

Comment: actually i am jus a noob to .htaccess rules can you help me by giving me a modified code ?

Comment: then easy way is to comment out the https line and add new line with http or local

Comment: @GauravRai can you please provide the modified code ?

Comment: @miken32 can you help me with the modified code ?

Comment: I added an answer for you with the code you need.

Answer (score 1):

Add this after `RewriteEngine on`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
```